# jsp foreach on jdbc list<map> format

Tags: sql, jsp, model-view-controller, jdbc

so im having a little problem with my code. I used jdbc to make a query to our SQL database in our DAO like so:

```
List<Map<String,Object>> results = namedjdbcTemplate.queryForList(FINDALL,     namedParameters);
```

Which is then passed up from the service to the controller where it is added to our model:

```
List<Map<String,Object>> locations = cmsAttributeService.getAttributeList(id);
        model.addAttribute("locationlist", locations);
```

I then need to display all the entries in our jsp. Currently i do so like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${locationlist}" var="list">  
<tr> 
  <td>
   <c:out value="${list }"></c:out>
  </td>
 </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

My problem is the formatting it returns, for example:

```
{=UCMDB2.Project.name}
```

How do i get it to return just 'UCMDB2.Project.name' dropping the {=  }? Ive tried all sorts of other calls like using list.value, list.key, all of which either break it entirely or blank the results out. Im fairly sure it should be something simple that im just missing. Anyone got any clues?

Comment: Each item of the list is a map. A map has a number of keys, each associated with a value. If you don't know the keys, and don't tell what you want to print, it's hard to help you. All I can say is that you should not return a list of maps, but a list of custome java beans, with well-defined and typed properties.

Answer (score 0):

Changed it to `List <String>` and it worked.